# Need regex pattern for input text box allowing numbers between 0 to 100 and up to 2 decimals eg., 0.22 to 100.00

Tags: regex, angular7

I need a regex pattern to allow numbers from 0 to 100 with decimals.

I tried the following pattern, but it allows numbers greater than 100:

```
^ 100(\.[0]{ 1, 2}) ?| ([0 - 9] | [1 - 9][0 - 9])(\.[0 - 9]{ 1, 2}) ? $
```

Comment: There are way too many spaces in your pattern. Spaces are significant in regular expressions.

Comment: `^(A|B)$` means: `A` from start to end OR `B` from start to end. Whereas `^A|B$` means: `A` at start OR `B` at the end. Here one more pattern idea: [`^(?:[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?|100(?:\.00?)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/UDZyf3/3).

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern you include matching spaces which have meaning.

Without the spaces the [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/jy5HVc/1) would be `^100(\.[0]{1,2})?|([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

To match either 100 with an optional dot and 1 or 2 zeroes OR match a digit 0-99 followed by 1 or 2 decimals so you could wrap the whole pattern in a non capturing group `^(?:....)$` using the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for either of the possibilities:

```
^(?:100(?:\.0{1,2})?|(?:[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tCSUcR/1)

Comment: In your demo its working perfect, but when i integrate pattern in my code its not as expected. here is my component code snippet:  case 'CO':
        manItem.reference.min = 0;
        manItem.reference.max = 100;
        manItem.reference.pattern = '^(?:100(?:\.0{1,2})?|(?:[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$';
        value = '%';
        break;
    }
    return value;

Comment: html :-->  <input [formControl]="frmCtrls['reference']" [(ngModel)]="reference" 
                class="form-control d-inline-block w-75 {{(formSubmitted && frmCtrls['reference'].invalid) ? 'ng-invalid ng-touched' : ''}}"
                type="{{ref.reference.type}}" (focus)="toggleFocus()" (blur)="toggleFocus()"
                *ngIf="ref.reference['type'] == 'text' || ref.reference['type'] == 'number'" maxlength="15" pattern="{{ref.reference.pattern}}" min="{{ref.reference.min}}" max="{{ref.reference.max}}" />

Comment: What do you mean by is not working as expected? Are the `min` and the `max` that you set on the `reference` working? Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: i meant when am enter 0.25 or 1.55 digits into input its  going invalid . Please see my code above.

Comment: If I take the settings from the code it seems to work. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeYRoM What is the value of the type property when you are evaluating the pattern? Is the value perhaps modified in between? Can you add some console.log statements to get the values?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/^(?:100(?:\.0{1,2})?)$|^(?:[1-9]\d?|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/FxoGO9/2

Comment: Yeah its working in regex debugger but not when i integrate same pattern in my code.which am applying dynamically.  i added my html/component code above. Please let me know clue why its not working in my app.